# Sum of infinite series involving cos$\theta$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum of following series:

$$1 + \frac{1}{4!} \cos 4\theta + \frac{1}{8!} \cos 8\theta + ...$$

My attempt:

I need hint to start. Thanks!

Comment: both. i thought about bringing in $e^{i\theta}$ but that doesnt help much here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***HINT***
$$\frac 12(\cosh(x)+\cos(x))=\frac 12\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {x^{2k}}{(2k)!}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {(-1)^kx^{2k}}{(2k)!}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {x^{4k}}{(4k)!}$$
and you have:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\cos(4k\theta)}{(4k)!}$$
and $\cos(x)=\Re(e^{ix})$

> The answer turns out to be: $\dfrac 12 \left(\cos(\sin(\theta))\cosh(\cos(\theta))+ \cos(\cos(\theta))\cosh(\sin(\theta))\right)$

Comment: answer is Real art of 1/2(cosh($e^{i\theta})+cos(e^{i\theta}$)) isnt it?

Comment: @Foggy Yes it is. Use trig addition formulas, and the fact that $\cosh(ix)=\cos(x)$ and you'll get there.

Comment: @GeorgSaliba How did you do that awesome thing with the answer? like, it appears when the cursor is hovering on it..